# Delete vs. move to trash

Tags: kubuntu, filesystem

If I select a dozen or so files and choose Move to Trash it takes nearly a minute for the process to complete. If I choose Delete, they're gone instantly.

Since under the hood, they're more or less the same process of changing or removing a pointer, why the time discrepancy? Is there a way to speed up Move to Trash?

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
  KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
  KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
  Qt Version: 5.15.3
  Kernel Version: 6.2.0-36-generic (64-bit)
  Graphics Platform: X11
  Processors: 4 × Intel Xeon CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
  Memory: 15.5 GB RAM
  Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: I don't use Kubuntu, so I don't really know about "Delete".  Are you saying when you right-click on a file, you have both a "Move to Trash" option and a "Delete" option?  Under Ubuntu, I only have the former.  Or, by Delete, you meant the `rm` command within a shell?

Comment: There is more involved than your description; I'd expect you to wish for items that in the trash to appear in the trash meaning a creation of directory entry is required for each...  Trash does involve more work  (*not just inode pointer move as you seem to imply*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since, under the hood, they're more or less the same process of changing or removing a pointer, why the time discrepancy? Is there a way to speed up Move to Trash?

That is a wrong assumption. On a Linux ext4 file system, it takes longer to delete files than to move files on the same volume due to the different operations involved in each process.

Deleting a file involves following steps:

1. **Unlinking the file**: This removes the reference to the file from the directory structure, making it invisible to the user.
2. **Marking data blocks as free**: The data blocks that were previously used to store the file's contents are marked as free, indicating that they can be used by other files. However, the data itself is not actually deleted from the disk at this point.
3. **Updating filesystem metadata**: The filesystem metadata, which keeps track of the file's location and size, is updated to reflect the deleted file.

When moving a file on a same volume, there is only a need to unlink the file (step 1) then link it again into the new location.

1. **Unlinking the file**: This removes the reference to the file from the directory structure, making it invisible to the user.
2. **Linking the file**: This makes the file visible in the new location in the directory structure.